# If, in C/C++, we use #define, what about in Java?

Tags: java

Okay so, if I am not mistaken, in C or C++ we use the code below to shorten or substitute the statement to a different one. So you can just write `P` rather than `printf` as a command right?

```
#define P printf
```

Then how do we do that in Java?

Comment: You don't do that.  Java doesn't support macros / #defines.  (And horrible use-cases like this are part of the reason why it doesn't.  Convenience macros like this make your code hard for anyone else to read.  Just don't do it!)

Comment: You _were_ mistaken :-)  Changed the `#define` to the correct one.

Comment: Java like to have variable type defined so the satellite does not fall on someone head like in C/C++ example.

Answer (score 4):

Java does not have macros, or a pre-processing step. 
One must realize that with every programming language comes its own set of tools. 
Many times MACROS are used where C++ templates or Java generics can be used, for example in case of a MAX macro. 
If you really want to have a pre processing state, you should consider inserting a step to your build system (i.e - maven pluggin) that will go over your "Java code with macros", generate real Java files from it (similar to how inline functions behave in C++), and then compile the generated java code. 
You can find examples to it for example in case where Java code is generated from XSD or other schemas, so theoretically, why not generate it from "Java with macros code"? 
If you look for example at project [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) you will see they introduce a "properties" systax to Java, but in fact they just introduced IDE plugins (so the code does not look "broken" or "in error" when you code with your favorite IDE), and they introduced mavan steps/goals so you can actually build something developed with Lombok. 
Maybe you should adopt a similar approach, if this is that crucial for you (actually in past , prior to JDK 5, this is how "annotations" were used in some frameworks, but you should have a really good reason to do that in your code).

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have a preprocessor step like the languages you enumerated (the C macro language is handled by the preprocessor). You can make a `static final` function, or you could use [cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/index.html#Top) to pre-process your Java src (which I would not recommend because it wouldn't work with standard tools). Another somewhat similar alternative (but only in the sense of being able to omit a class name by adding a symbol to a local namespace) might be the [static import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html).

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

// ...

out.println("Hello, World"); // <-- System.out.println
```

Comment: I would strongly object defining static imports as a way to have MACROs.
Java simply doesn't have them.

Comment: @YairZaslavsky Tried to add a little clarification, obviously `static imports` aren't MACROs and I don't think I was saying that they were.

Answer (score 0):

java doesn't have any internal preprocessor but if it is strongly desired by project (usually by mobile project where needed small code corrections for many destination devices) then external tools can be used, somebody uses even C/C++ preprocessor to preprocess sources, I use my own [java-comment-preprocessor](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor) but anyway all java preprocessors, I have seen, don't allow such tricks as C/C++ preprocessor does, because preprocessor directives are not supported on the java language level